# Swift scroll to bottom of table that has only blank sections

Tags: swift

I am trying to scroll my table to the bottom every time a new section is added. They section may or may not have any rows but it still needs to scroll to the bottom. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.bounds.size.height + tableView.contentInset.bottom);
    tableView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I had to run a check to make sure the contentSize was greater than the bounds otherwise it was pushing content to the bottom of the container. Otherwise, PERFECT!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but one is the following. You should call this when `tableview` has been loaded.

```
func scrollDown(animated: Bool) {
        if self.numberOfRowsInSection(0) > 0 {
            self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: animated)
        }
    }
```