# Start UITableView from the last cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show the last cell first in a tableview like whatsapp did. I don't want a scrolling animation. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: just reverse your array

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361316/swift-scroll-to-bottom-of-table-that-has-only-blank-sections/38361555#38361555

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to reverse your tableview cells? If yes, do what Anbu said, reverse your datasource array instead. Or do you want the tableView to scrollDown to last cell?

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

**please note:** animate is no

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by transforming the UITableView and any views you use in it, including UITableViewCell.

First invert the tableview by setting the transform,

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
```

then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to set the same transform to cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     //This is important, since we are inverting the tableview , all subview must be inverted as well
    cell.transform = chatTableView.transform

    return cell
}
```

but this way you can load cells in recent first order, make sure all subviews is using the same transform as the tableView